# How do I get the file location of libraries imported by Python

Tags: python, python-2.6

Considering this line of Python code:

```
import foo
```

how do I then find the location on disk of the file that contains the source code to be executed in foo?

(And I'm on Win7)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the information in

```
foo.__file__
```

Note that not all modules come from files, though.  Some modules are also compiled directly into the interpreter, and those modules won't have a `__file__` attribute.

A list of the modules included in the interpreter can be found in [`sys.builtin_module_names`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).

Comment: And some are compiled from C, and won't have the source code directly available.

Comment: Thanks Sven. But Python told me the module I was importing had no __ file __ attribute (spaces added to prevent default __bold__ behaviour), and it's definitely not compiled in the interpreter. I'm trying to distinguish between piston 0.2.2 installed in python, and a separate fork of the piston source code I have copied inside my django project location.

Comment: Actually, all modules not compiled into the interpreter should have a `__file__` attribute, regardless if they are C extensions or loaded from `.pyc` files or whatever.  What version of Python are you using?  Anyway, You can also try and use `imp.find_module()` to find out what file Python is going to import.

Comment: dynamically generated modules, which can be created with `types.ModuleType` may not have a `__file__`  attribute.  If not, you're out of luck.  Another possibility is that what you think is a module is, in fact, a class, which is being used like a module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the value of `__file__` when the module does not have a one-to-one mapping to a file in the file-system. Specifically, if it is loading a module found within a ZIP file, I'm not sure what `__file__` will look like. (When I've needed such mappings, I've used tuples with ("path/to/file.zip", "path/within/zip/module.pyc") but that was a result of walking sys.path manually.) It wouldn't surprise me if it just set `__file__` to `None`.

When it is an issue as to which module of the same name will be loaded, it is always the first one found on the `sys.path`.

It is possible to `sys.path.insert(0, some_dir)` before you do your first import of the package to tweak things manually. (In the environment, this is set with [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).)

Ideally, you can find out which is being used simply by checking `PYTHONPATH` and/or `sys.path`. If the wrong one is being loaded, the only way to fix it is with `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`.